# custom jquery selector doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.modal-footer button').attr('data-print','').text('Print');

$(document).off('click', '.modal-footer button["data-print"]').on('click','.modal-footer button["data-print"]',function(){
   alert('fire');
});
```

I expect the code execute from top the bottom, so the custom selector should work, but it didn't, what's wrong there?

Comment: What r u trying to do? And what you want to achieve by this line `$('.modal-footer button').attr('data-print','').text('Print');`

Comment: `'.modal-footer button["data-print"]'` will not match any element as you have changed the attribute!

Comment: Try `.modal-footer button[data-print='']`. Btw, you should provide your HTML code as well for this kind of question.

Comment: Did you try this? `'.modal-footer button[data-print=""]'`

Comment: @HarryBomrah The OP is adding an empty data attribute and setting the text.

Comment: @RayonDabre If the OP removes the quotes (as I mentioned in my answer) it will work fine. You don't need to provide a value of the attribute in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes around the attribute name in the selector. Try this:

```
$(document)
    .off('click', '.modal-footer button[data-print]')
    .on('click', '.modal-footer button[data-print]', function(){
        alert('fire');
    });
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/785502mz/)